# How to share the logging file between classes in two different Modules in Python

Tags: python, logging

I know how to log from different Python modules. But in my case I have two different classes in but I want to create the log file form the main module but keep on logging in different Modules.

**main.py**

```
import logging
from mod import Mod


class Main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        logging.basicConfig(filename='sample.log', level=logging.INFO)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        print 'Starting of main..'
        self.logger.info('Starting of main..')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    md = Mod()
    m = Main()
```

**mod.py**

```
import logging


class Mod(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # logging.basicConfig(filename='sample.log', level=logging.INFO)
        print "In the Mod class"
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.info('In the Mod Class')
```

Here if I comment the `logging.basicConfig(filename='sample.log', level=logging.INFO)` in `mod.py` it is only logging from the `main.py` but when I uncomment that line, it works. But this doesn't happen in modules with out class. Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Can you try putting the `logging.basicConfig(filename='sample.log', level=logging.INFO)` call at the start of your `main`?

Comment: The issue is that because you're creating `Mod()` before creating `Main()`, the logger hasn't been initialiased at the ponit that `Mod.init` calls `self.logger.info('In the Mod Class')`

Comment: @TomDalton Thanks...that solved the problem...I didn't even notice the problem.